# While converting NSString to NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I try to convert `NSString` to `NSDate` with this code:

```
NSString *dateString=[[NSString alloc] init];
dateString = [[messageArray objectAtIndex:i] tim_dte];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm,yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
msg.date = dateFromString;
```

But `msg.Date` is `nil` even if `dateString` shows the correct date string. What am I missing?

Comment: whats your `dateString` can you show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm,yyyy/MM/dd"];
```

into and try

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"];
```

**Update**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"];
// use simple 
msg.date =   [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016/05/06 12:36"];
  NSLog(@"final date == %@",dateFromString);
//NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016/05/06 12:36"];

// NSLog(@"final date == %@",dateFromString);
```

Comment: Thanks so Date format also important while converting nsstring to nsdate right?

Comment: @Bittoo -- 100 % manodatry bro, if it is modified always you get nil

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

```
NSString *dateString=[[NSString alloc] init];
dateString =[[messageArray objectAtIndex:i] tim_dte];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
msg.date=dateFromString;
```

hope its helpful

Comment: why you allocated the date here

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to convert NSString to NSDate

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-05-06";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-01T06:25:47Z"];
NSTimeZone *pdt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:pdt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"K:mm a, z"];
NSString * updated String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```